# ¿Cómo invertir una tabla de acuerdo a fecha?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-tabla

Estoy intentando invertir esta tabla de acuerdo a la fecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De tal manera que el resultado final al invertirla, sea este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se aprecia, las fechas se hacen `encabezados`, pero `sin repetir` las fechas, y de acuerdo a cada fecha, se alinea el monto de cada fecha, poniendo por `default 0` a los demás `campos` que no se ocupan.

He realizado este código, pero ya no tengo idea de cómo crear la nueva tabla en base a la original:

```js
var montos = [];
         var fechas = [];  
         var datos = [];
         var body = $('#principal').find('tbody > tr > td');//tabla principal
         var header = $('#encabezado > th'); 

         function unique(list) {
       var result = [];
       $.each(list, function(i, e) {
           if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
       });
       return result;
  }

         for(var i = 0; i < body.length; i++){

          if(body[i].innerHTML.indexOf("-") != -1){
           fechas.push(body[i].innerHTML);
          }else{
           montos.push(body[i].innerHTML);           
          }         
         }         

         for(var j = 0; j < fechas.length; j++){

          datos.push({
           montos: montos[j],
           fechas: fechas[j]
     });                 
         }


         for(var k = 0; k < unique(fechas).length; k++){
          
          $('#encabezado').append('<th class = "th">'+ unique(fechas)[k] +'</th>');
         }


         var cant_montos = [];//almacenará la cant_montosidad de montos que hay por fecha

         for(var m = 0; m < $('.th').length; m++){//recorre los th de la tabla nueva
          
          var cont = 0;

          datos.forEach(function(i,element) {  //recorre el array de objetos         

           if($('.th')[m].innerHTML == i.fechas){ //si lo que tiene el nuevo encabezado coincide con lo que hay en el objeto fechas
            cont += 1; //irá contando las veces que el encabezado coincida con las fechas en el array    
            console.log($('.th')[m].innerHTML+ "  "+ i.montos);    
           }
    });

    cant_montos.push(cont);//guardará el último numero que ha contado en cada iteración en el array
         }
```

```css
div{
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .contenedor{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
 }
 .contenido{
  height:100px;
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
<table id="principal" border="" class="contenido" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Monto</th>    
    <th>Fecha</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>2019-01-02</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2019-01-02</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>2019-01-03</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <!--Tabla nueva-->
  <table border="" class="contenido" >
   <thead>
    <tr id="encabezado"></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="cuerpo"> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
    
    </div>
```

Como se puede ver en el resultado de la consola, he logrado ordenar los montos de acuerdo a su fecha, es ahí donde me he atorado. No sé si lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta o hay mejores formas de hacerlo. Ya que como lo he mencionado anteriormente, necesito crear la nueva tabla en base a la principal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:
no es del todo eficiente pero creo que te servira

> **nota:** no suelo utilizar jquery pero si gustas puedes cambiarlo a este

```js
// selector de items
var $ = (s) => document.querySelectorAll(s);

// recuepara la data dentro de la tabla
var data = $("td");

//seleccionara el encabezado
var thead = $("#encabezado")[0];

//selecciona el cuerpo
var tbody = $("#cuerpo")[0];

// array objetos para la data recuperada
var columnas={};

// cantidad de items c[1] guardara la cantidad de items del recorrido
// y c[0] guardara el valor maximo de iteraciones
var c=[];
c[0]=0;

// recorremos todos los td del documento
for (let i = 1; i < data.length; i+=2) {
        // inicalizamos un arreglo
        let values=[];
        // ponemos a c[0] en 0 por cada iteracion no servira para saber la cantidad de resultados
        c[1]=0;
        //recorremos nuevamente todos los td
        for(let j = 1; j < data.length; j+=2){
            // validamos que encontremos 2 fechas iguales
            if (data[j].innerText == data[i].innerText ) {
                // agregamos al arreglo la posicion pares que son los valores
                values.push(data[j-1].innerText);
                //le sumamos 1 a c
                c[1]+=1;
            }
        }
        //validamos que c[1] sea mayor para cambiar el valor de c[0]
       c[0] = c[1] > c[0] ? c[1] : c[0];
       // agregamos el arreglo de valores a la fecha
       columnas[data[i].innerText]=values;
}


//recorremos la cantidad de items
for(let i=0; i<c[0]; i++){
//agregamos los tr de los tbody
tbody.innerHTML+=`<tr></tr>`;
   //recorremos las columnas
   for(let x in columnas){
    //validamos que i ==0 para que no repita mas de 1 vez los thead
   if(i==0)thead.innerHTML += `<th>${x}</th>`;
    //seleccionamos el  tbody con id cuerpo en la posicion p y le agregamos un td 
    $("tbody[id='cuerpo'] tr")[i].innerHTML+= (columnas[x][i] ==undefined) ? `<td>0</td>` :`<td>${columnas[x][i]}</td>` ;
   }
}
```

```css
div{
  border-radius: 5px;
 }
 .contenedor{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
 }
 .contenido{
  height:100px;
  width:40%;
  float:left;
  margin: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contenedor">
<table id="principal" border="" class="contenido" >
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Monto</th>    
    <th>Fecha</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>20</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>2019-01-01</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>2019-01-02</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>2019-01-02</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>2019-01-03</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>70</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>80</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>90</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>2019-01-04</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <!--Tabla nueva-->
  <table border="" class="contenido" >
   <thead>
    <tr id="encabezado"></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="cuerpo"> 
   </tbody>
  </table>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: ya ahora si es mas optimo que antes.... el tiempor redujo de `4.376953125ms` a `2.301025390625ms` gran mejora diria!